# What is the expected SRID value during importing shapefile with TDGeoImport tool (Teradata Database)?

Tags: srid, teradata

I can successfully upload my SHP file into Teradata database using the *TDGeoImport* tool. The aim is to publish the geospatial table in Teradata to GeoServer as (web) map services.

I'm curious as to how to use the *-a_srs* parameter. All examples in the references related to Teradata Geospatial skip this *-a_srs* parameter.

And by *references* here i mean:

1. Teradata Geospatial Utilities - User Guide, Release 16.00 B035-2519-086K, November 2016, a 36-pages PDF, [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/download.cfm?ItemID=1007238).
2. Teradata Geospatial Utilities Demonstration : Executing TDGeoImport (a web page), [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Utilities%2FB035-2519-086K%2FExecutingTDGeoImport_DEMO_2519.html%23wwID0EDHCI).
3. GeoServer and Teradata, version 1.0, July 2011, a 20-pages PDF, [here](http://download.teradata.com/download/cdn/doc/extensibility/geospatial/geoserver/GeoServer_Teradata_v1.0.pdf).

This *-a_srs* parameter is not mandatory and meant for defining the SRID/coordinate system. However, it turned out that there's serious consequence on how the parameter was used. See below:

[image: Different usage of -a_srs and its effect]

Interestingly, the above table shows that with the case of TDGeoImport using *-a_srs* parameter in a way that gives a table with SRID = 0, Geoserver can successfully render the layer. And reversely, using *-a_srs* parameter in a way that gives SRID = 4326 or 1619, Geoserver fails to render the layer.

And here's the XML error message from Geoserver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://MYHOST/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="internalError"> Rendering process failed java.io.IOExceptionjava.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.33] [Error 7548] [SQLState HY000] 13 ST_Intersects: ST_Geometry values cannot have unequal srid&apos;s. [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.33] [Error 7548] [SQLState HY000] 13 ST_Intersects: ST_Geometry values cannot have unequal srid&apos;s.
```

Now the question are:

1. How to use this -*a_srs* parameter?
2. What is the expected SRID value during importing shapefile with TDGeoImport tool?
3. What is the risk of skipping this *-a_srs* parameter ?

My environment are:

- Teradata Database 15.00.04.04
- GeoServer 2.10.1 on JBOSS EAP 6 on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 64-bit

Comment: Your complaint about 32-bit operation appears unrelated to your question. It therefore serves as a distraction from your Question, which should only have one question.

Answer (score 1):

Option -a_srs is probably the same as in ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html but it is indeed not documented which syntax it accepts. It can be either epsg code `epsg:4326` or proj4 string `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"`, name of the ESRI .prj file or OGC WKT definition. In your case `epsg:xxxx` is correct.

The GeoServer error means that database has one SRID and GeoServer sends a query with a spatial filter that is using another SRID or no SRID at all. That feels like misconfiguration on the GeoServer side. Check your setting in the Coordinate Reference Systems http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html. Native SRS must be the same that you have in the database.

Risk of using an undefined SRID is that you can't reproject data into other SRID's and the geometries in the spatial filters which you use must also be in an undefined projection.